# Plug in numbers to find relationship between numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A total of k passengers went on a bus trip. Each of the n buses that were used to transport the passengers could seat a maximum of x passengers. If one bus had 3 empty seats and the remaining buses were filled, which of the following expresses the relationship among n,x, and k?

I only desire a plugging in numbers approach to solve this problem. No algebra.

The problem is I can't think of numbers that would work. Can you help?

A. nx-3=k

B. nx+3=k

C. n+x+3=k

D. nk=x+3

E. nk=x-3

Comment: why "No Algebra"?,(number of seats per bus)*(number of buses)=k+3

Comment: Here are some numbers that work: 90 passengers, 3 busses, each bus with room for 31 passengers. Or 60 passengers, 7 busses (more like minivans, actually), each holding 9 passengers.

Answer (score 1):

$k$ passengers were divided among $n$ buses:

- $1$ bus was filled with $x-3$ passengers
- $n-1$ buses were filled with $x$ passengers

Therefore, $k = 1\cdot(x-3)+(n-1)\cdot{x} = nx-3$.